# Problem to print list of tuple for every sentence seperately

Tags: list, nlp, tuples, pos-tagger

If we have situation like that
[(ali,noun),(ahmad, noun),(play , verb)], [(read, verb), (is, helping verb), (waqar, noun)]
I want to print only verb from these list of tuple but when i print it will show whole data list are merging?

Answer (score 0):

Done with Answer

num = [x[0] for x in tagged if x[1] == 'VBG' or x[1] == 'VBD' or x[1] == 'VBN' or x[1]== 'VB' or x[1]=='JJ']